# tls error - EOF - Fluentbit pushing logs to Splunk

Tags: kubernetes, splunk, fluent

We are trying to push logs into Splunk with FluentBit service that is running on a different POD but within the same namespace of a Kubernetes Cluster. Unfortunately, we seem to be hitting this error due to which the logs are not being sent to Splunk.

```
[error] [tls] error: unexpected EOF
```

The above is from the fluentbit log. The fluent bit configuration is as follows

```
 [OUTPUT]
    Name splunk
    Match *
    Host splunk-deployment-server-service.devnm.svc
    Port 8088
    storage.total_limit_size 10M
    splunk_token Splunk e2c0fc05-d64e-49ce-9094-10617a7528c8
    tls on
    tls.verify off
    tls.debug 4
```

Versions:
Splunk 9.1.0.1
Fluent Bit v2.0.4

As mentioned earlier, both Fluent & Splunk are running as PODs in the same namespace of a k8s cluster. What could be going wrong, please

Regards
Bala

Comment: what have you tried? What other error(s) come from Fluentbit? What error(s) show in Splunk `_internal` log?

Comment: @warren thanks for your response. I don't see any other *internal*.log than jura_check_splunk_internal_library.log. 

In the splunkd.log, i see a repeat of the following "Warning"

*WARN  IntrospectionGenerator:resource_usage [8910 ExecProcessor] -   SystemInfo - Found zero cpus assigned to the container*

Not sure if this is related to the "unexpected EOF" error.